# How do I get credentials of python-social-auth for google drive sdk?

Tags: python, django, oauth-2.0, google-drive-api, google-oauth

I use django for my web framework,
I found [python-social-auth](https://github.com/omab/python-social-auth) is a good package for OAuth.
And I also want to get access google drive from google OAuth2.
I saw some sample code on [Google Drive SDK](https://developers.google.com/drive/auth/web-server):

```
from apiclient.discovery import build

def build_service(credentials):

  http = httplib2.Http()
  http = credentials.authorize(http)
  return build('drive', 'v2', http=http)
```

So, Looks like I need to get credentials to instantiate server objects.
How do I do so that can get credentials?
Or what do I do can get use google drive?

Answer (score 1):

I've run into the same case, and I've been seeing how oauth2client works, so I've generated the credential from the data obtained by the authentication with python-social-auth, I put this logic inside a pipeline when a user logged in the website for the first time. As follows:

```
import datetime
from django.conf import settings
from oauth2client import GOOGLE_REVOKE_URI, GOOGLE_TOKEN_URI
from oauth2client.client import OAuth2Credentials, _extract_id_token
from oauth2client.django_orm import Storage
from website.models import CredentialsModel


def set_google_credentials(strategy, details, response, user=None, *args, **kwargs):
    if user and kwargs.get('is_new'):
        token_expiry = datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(seconds=int(response.get('expires_in')))
        id_token = _extract_id_token(response.get('id_token'))
        credential = OAuth2Credentials(
            access_token=response.get('access_token'),
            client_id=settings.SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_PLUS_KEY,
            client_secret=settings.SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_PLUS_SECRET,
            refresh_token=response.get('refresh_token'),
            token_expiry=token_expiry,
            token_uri=GOOGLE_TOKEN_URI,
            user_agent=None,
            revoke_uri=GOOGLE_REVOKE_URI,
            id_token=id_token,
            token_response=response)
        storage = Storage(CredentialsModel, 'id', user, 'credential')
        storage.put(credential)
```

then in my settings:

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE = (
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_details',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_uid',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_user',
    'social.pipeline.user.get_username',
    'social.pipeline.user.create_user',
    'myapp.pipeline.set_google_credentials'    
    # more pipelines
)
```

then when I need credentials for a user:

**UPDATE**: As [@bcoover](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4900944/bcoover) noted the results got from `Storage` needed to be decoded and depickled.

```
user = # get a user instance, from the request for example
storage = Storage(CredentialsModel, 'id', user, 'credential')
import pickle, base64
credentials = (pickle.loads(base64.b64decode(storage.get())))
# do what ever you want with the credentials
```

this approach works for me at the moment, but if someone has a better way to do, I'll be grateful. The Storage and CredentialsModel are from https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/django

Comment: I tried this but storage.get() returns a huge hex string starting with '\\x67414e'

Here are my imports:
from oauth2client.django_orm import Storage
from socrademy.apps.user.models import CredentialsModel
from social.apps.django_app.utils import load_strategy
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

Answer (score 1):

This was immensely helpful, thanks @eyscode! 
I had the same problem as @areyoueye, and it turns out after looking at the Google code, the results needed to be decoded and depickled, and then it works great!
Here is the modified code:

```
import pickle
...
storage = Storage(GoogleCredential, 'id', user, 'credential')
credentials = (pickle.loads(base64.b64decode(storage.get())))
...
```

Then doing the print(), you should get an object as output like this:

```
...
print(credentials)
<oauth2client.client.OAuth2Credentials object at 0x7fa2837af630>
```

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a better solution from this Gist here: https://github.com/python-social-auth/social-core/issues/125#issuecomment-389070863

It seems better in the sense that it uses the python social auth mechanisms for refreshing the token in case the Google API requests it. This means that the refreshed token goes to the DB.