# Google API storage returns string, not credentials object

Tags: python, django, google-api, gmail-api

I'm trying to use the google-api for python. 
I've managed to store the credentials in a `CredentialsField` (basically copying [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20801229/how-do-i-get-credentials-of-python-social-auth-for-google-drive-sdk)) implementation.

I can get a storage object:

```
>>> storage = Storage(CredentialsModel, 'id', user, 'credential')   
>>> storage
<oauth2client.django_orm.Storage object at 0x7f1f8f1260f0>
```

no problem. But when I try to get the credentials object:

```
>>> credential = storage.get()
>>> credential
```

I just get a massive string (7482 characters) instead of a credentials object. What gives? (I think the string might be a bytearray, since it begins with `'\\x67414e6a6`.

I'm also using Python 3.

Any thoughts on why I'm getting a string instead of a Credentials object?

Comment: I think its problem with credential object. It has some random value in the credential reference. Try to include some getters and setters in the credential class which will help you to print the credential class.

Answer (score 2):

I've actually found the answer if you still need it:

The problem is that the class CredentialFields in django_orm defined a **metaclass** variable, which isn't supported in python3 anymore.

Therefore, it is necessary to change it to something like this:

class CredentialsField(models.Field, metaclass=models.SubfieldBase):

someone has opened an issue in the github repo:

https://github.com/google/oauth2client/issues/168

Answer (score 0):

My solution for python3, django 1.8 with postgres database:

There is a missing step right before saving the byte data to database, and after retrieving the data back from database: The byte data need to be converted to/from string first. You can convert byte to string and vice versa with `decode("utf-8")` and `encode("utf-8")`.

You also do not need the  `__metaclass__`, but need to have `get_prep_value()` and `from_db_value()` functions.
The entire class `CredentialsField` should be rewritten like so:

```
class CredentialsField(models.Field):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if 'null' not in kwargs:
            kwargs['null'] = True
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_internal_type(self):
        return "TextField"

    def to_python(self, value):
        if value is None:
            return None
        if isinstance(value, oauth2client.client.Credentials):
            return value

        value = value.encode("utf-8")  # string to byte

        return pickle.loads(base64.b64decode(value))

    def from_db_value(self, value, expression, connection, context):
        return self.to_python(value)

    def get_db_prep_value(self, value, connection, prepared=False):
        if value is None:
            return None

        byte_repr = base64.b64encode(pickle.dumps(value))

        return byte_repr.decode("utf-8")  # byte to string

    def get_prep_value(self, value):
        return self.get_db_prep_value(value)
```